# How can I set the initial supply of a token to unlimited in an ethereum contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-deployment

I am creating a token contract with solidity. I am using this link: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard

Here is the snapshot of code:

```
contract FixedSupplyToken {
      string public  symbol = "FIXED";
      string public  name = "Example Fixed Supply Token";
      uint8 public   decimals = 18;
      uint256 _totalSupply = XXX; // I want to set this to unlimited
```

I want `_totalSupply` to be unlimited. If this is not possible, is there any way to increase the value of `_totalSupply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The totalSupply will be pretty much limited to the uint256 type: (2^256)-1

What you could do however, is to set the `_totalSupply = 0` (or maximum value) and erase all the checks on totalSupply and simply assign balances to the the `balances[address]` as you wish to.

I'm not aware of any check against `totalSupply` that's somehow required.

Comment: Another solution might be to create a contract that generates contracts that hold balanaces upto the uint256 limit and acts as an interface to them - that's however a general scaling problem